# display "no results found" after search

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I'm a novice at jQuery but have been able to use a few scripts I found to get the results I want with one exception. The page I'm working on has 4 drop down menus which allow the user to make a selection from each menu and then click a submit button which returns the results from a list.

Currently if you make a few selections and nothing if found you only get a blank page.  I need to display "No Results Found".   A few scripts I've seen here would require me to rewrite what I have but I think there is a simple solution.  If not, its back to the keyboard for me.

Here is the code on jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/LbUfe/

Here is the script I'm using to make the selections.

```
<script type="text/javascript">     
        $(document).ready(function()
        {               
            $("#btnFilter").click(function()
            {
                var portfolio   = $("#portfolio").val();
                var strategy    = $("#strategy").val();
                var geoFocus    = $("#geoFocus").val();
                var spendType   = $("#spendType").val();
                var portfolioSelector = '';
                var strategySelector = '';      
                var geoFocusSelector = '';
                var spendTypeSelector = '';

                if (portfolio == "all" && strategy == "all" && geoFocus == "all" && spendType == "all")                     
                {
                    //show all items in list - working
                    $(".item").show();
                }

                else
                {
                    if (strategy != "all")
                    {
                        strategySelector = '.' + strategy
                    }

                    if (portfolio != "all")
                    {
                        portfolioSelector = '.' + portfolio 
                    }
                    if (geoFocus != "all")
                    {
                        geoFocusSelector = '.' + geoFocus
                    }
                    if (spendType != "all")
                    {
                        spendTypeSelector = '.' + spendType
                    }
                    $(".item").hide();
                    $(strategySelector + portfolioSelector + geoFocusSelector + spendTypeSelector).show(); 
                     }  

            });

        });
```

Here is the working page (minus the "No Results Found").

http://staging.humanityunited.org/

A quick example:  select 'Bangladesh' from 'Geographic Focus' menu, and 'Sponsorship' for 'Spending Type' menu and click submit.  You will get a blank page.

Comment: I updated my answer with working code and your fiddle updated with my solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add a check to see how many of the list element are visible.

```
var visibleElements = $('#colRight li:visible').length;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/LbUfe/5/

Comment: Thank you so much, thealexbaron. This is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: No problem! Don't forget to accept one of these as the answer to your question.

Answer (score 2):

As I can see in your html, all possible results do have a class .item.
Therefore, if no .item is showing, it means that its time to print the "no results found".
You can achieve this in jQuery:

```
if($('li.item:visible').length===0)) // no item visible
{
    // put code here to display your message
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the great advice, Freeman.  Both you and thealexbaron  have saved me a lot of time.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

```
$(strategySelector + portfolioSelector + geoFocusSelector + spendTypeSelector).show();
```

to

```
var $res = $(strategySelector + "," + portfolioSelector + "," + geoFocusSelector + "," + spendTypeSelector).show();
if ($res.length == 0) {
    $res.html("No results found");
}

$res.show();
```

([Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LbUfe/6/))

It looks like your problem was that you were appending all of those selectors so only things with ALL of those selectors would be shown. Ergo, I added comas between the selectors.

Comment: Thank you, Zachary. I will definitely try this.

Comment: No worries :) Let me know if you have any difficulties/questions.

Answer (score 0):

i think this is better

```
var ItemsCount=$(strategySelector + portfolioSelector + geoFocusSelector + spendTypeSelector).show().length;
if(ItemsCount= 0)
{
    //show your message
}
```

Comment: The problem is that he is appending all of those selectors so only things with ALL of those selectors will be shown - it is a bug.